# Compiling Error GSTreamer on Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, gstreamer

I am trying implementation GStreamer my personel project. I complied GStreamer tutorials successfully but I don't adding my project. I have 201 issues. Issues types same, like this;

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_g_main_context_new", referenced from:
      -[GStreamerBackend app_function] in GStreamerBackend.o
      -[GStreamerBackend app_function_audio] in GStreamerBackend.o
```

I don't understand anything. GStreamer tutorials wroten OBJC but I codding my project with swift. How can I solve this issue or how can I implement GStreamer from my project.

Comment: Please let know which project you are trying to compile. (provide links to project if any)

Comment: Basic swift project.

Comment: If you are trying to use Objective-C code from Swift, then follow the steps from this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-do-i-call-objective-c-code-from-swift